# EF Core is holding the LoaderAllocator alive

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**My Nuget Packages:**

GmodNET.API: 0.7.1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore: 6.0.1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions: 6.0.1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design: 6.0.1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational: 6.0.1
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.1
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql: 6.0.0

**The Situation**

I am using [Gmod.NET](https://github.com/GmodNET/GmodDotNet) that uses internally AssemblyLoadContext to load and unload my module.

**The Problem**

After creating a instance of my `DbContext`, I can't unload my module anymore.

The exception I get is:

> TestModule.dll can't be unloaded: there are remaining references or background threads still executing

The only code that is being executed in my module is the creation of a instance of my `DbContext`.

**What I tried and found out**

I tried to debug the memory to find out what is holding my LoaderAllocator alive (by following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/unloadability) and found out that [something in a ThreadPool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRGXO.png) is holding a reference to my LoaderAllocator.

I also tried not to create a instance of my `DbContext`. Loading and unloading worked as it should. As soon as I create instance of my DBContext, I can't unload it anymore.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How are you creating an instance of the DbContext? Are you using a container, and if so is that container set up with a compatible lifetime scope? (I.e. not using "Transient") Or are you new-ing one up, in which case are you disposing it properly such as with a `using` block?

Comment: I am using new-ing and dispose it with `using`. After some testing I found out that I actually can create a instance of `DbContext` and dispose it with `using`. But  if I load some data (e.g a entity from db) it can't unload anymore.

Comment: Hmm, while entity proxies do hold a reference to the context that spawned them by default that DbContext should still be able to be disposed. If any entity needs to exist beyond the end of the `using` block for it's DbContext you should use `AsNoTracking` to ensure the references are detached entirely. Ideally I would recommend projecting to a view model/DTO rather than passing detached entities.

Comment: I tried using `AsNoTracking`, same result. I made some images (https://imgur.com/a/MRZh82c) of the memory state after the failed unload. Here is my code too https://imgur.com/a/ZgplXGN.